# Datetime-local em @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho uma propriedade da model que vou guardar `DateTime`:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ}")]
public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
```

Quero converter em um campo html do tipo (`type="datetime-local"`)

```
<input type="datetime-local">
```

Com estou tentando fazer:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ}", new  {type = "datetime-local" })
```

Coloquei essa formatação, coloquei o type, coloquei o atributo na model, tentei com ApplyFormatInEditMode = true e false e nada funciona, no máximo fica `type="datetime"` e nda.

ele está ficando assim:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="DataInicio" name="DataInicio" type="datetime" value="">
```

Comment: Tenta tirar o DateTypeAttribute e muda para @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataInicio, "{0:yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ}", new  {type = "datetime-local" })

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei qual versão do MVC está utilizando, então aconselho a tentar usar o `TextBoxFor()`, que possui suporte para versões mais antigas.

O que deve ser feito é colocar o `@` antes do `type`, desta forma:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataInicio, new {@type = "datetime-local"})
```

Caso esteja com o MVC5 e queira utilizar o `EditorFor()`, você deve utilizar o `htmlAttributes`, desta forma:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "datetime-local" } })
```

Veja um exemplo funcional no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cWx0Wm).